# install unity package in to iphone?

Tags: iphone, unity

HI All,
 what is the steps of to install the unity package in to iphone and create a build (app file )that my client can also able to install in his iphone .

Thanks,
balraj.

Comment: Can someone with enough rep please add the iPhone tag?

Comment: come to http://answers.unity3d.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some tutorials that you might find useful from [UnifyCommunity](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=Tutorials).

Then there's this presentation over on Scribd regarding ["Unity iPhone Newbie Guide"](http://www.scribd.com/doc/15494658/Unity-iPhone-Newbie-Guide-Lesson1); maybe that's something you would like to read.

Then there's the [iPhone Publishing](http://unity3d.com/unity/features/iphone-publishing.html) page directly from the horses mouth over at Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Without putting your application in the iStore, you will need to configure a team environment set up with your developer account where you have both your device and your clients device added as a development devices. That being said, your client may need a developer account? Keep in mind that this might not be something the client really wants to do and their phone may need to be updated/synchronized/reformatted.

In any event, I think you will have to transfer your xcode files to the client and walk them through the deployment process if you don't have physical access to the device...

It gets a little hairy at this point, I am working on a project where were just trying to get all our developers and testers able to deploy to their iDevices it becomes a bit of a process for a simple development deploy.

Let us know how it works out...